# Tex Live 2015 on Windows 10: errors during update in Tex Live Manager

Tags: texlive, windows, fmtutil, update

In a brand new installation of Tex Live, the first time I tried to update installed packages (a few weeks after installation), I got many errors similar to the following:

```
fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine uptex failed (status 255), output:
c:\texlive\2015\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl: Unexpected non-option argument(s): fmtutil
Try "fmtutil --help" for more information.
C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:663: command failed with exit code 255:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2015\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl fmtutil --sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine uptex
```

Many errors like this one regarding `uptex` occurred concerning `pdftex`, `xetex`, `tex`, etc.

This first approach to Tex Live is not very attractive, is it advisable to go with MikTeX since I'm under Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See

http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-December/037540.html

It is a bug in TeXLive, should be fixed in tomorrows update or try it yourself by modifying the code.